# Inner Join Query on 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I don't know what is wrong here. I am running a query with a multiple join of 3 tables, the query below works perfectly...
Giving me the employee details, his age, if he requires the certificate and gives me info regarding the certificates expiry date, also puts a "-" in the next field if a certificate is not required - and as I said, this works like a charm...

```
    SELECT 
    `employee`.*,
    date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(`empl_dob`, '%Y') - 
      (date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(`empl_dob`, '00-%m-%d')) AS age,
    `certs`.`cert_medical_restrict`, 
    IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`='n/a', `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`, 
        IF( `certs`.`cert_medical` = 0, 'No Cert',
             IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 1, 'X', 
                IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 30, 'ES', 'ok')))
        ) AS medical,       
    IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`='n/a', '-', 
        IF( `certs`.`cert_medical` = 0, '-', (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())))) AS medicalx   
    FROM `employee` 
    JOIN `jobtitle` 
    ON `employee`.`jobtitle_id` = `jobtitle`.`jobtitle_id` 
    JOIN `certs` 
    ON `certs`.`empl_idno` = `employee`.`empl_idno` 
    WHERE `employee`.`empl_no` = '10517602'
```

...But for my next query, I need to display the actual expiry date of the certificate, the queries look very much the same, but without the extra IF statements...

```
    SELECT 
    `employee`.*,
    date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(`empl_dob`, '%Y') - 
       (date_format(now(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(`empl_dob`, '00-%m-%d')) AS age,
    `certs`.`cert_medical_restrict`, 
    IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`='n/a', `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`, 
        IF( `certs`.`cert_medical` = 0, 'No Cert', (DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)))) AS medical,       
    IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`='n/a', '-', 
        IF( `certs`.`cert_medical` = 0, '-', (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())))) AS medicalx   
    FROM `employee` 
    JOIN `jobtitle` 
    ON `employee`.`jobtitle_id` = `jobtitle`.`jobtitle_id` 
    JOIN `certs` 
    ON `certs`.`empl_idno` = `employee`.`empl_idno` 
    WHERE `employee`.`empl_no` = '10517602'
```

Now I get this error "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'if' "
I cannot get my head around it, I have checked to see if the three tables differ from each other, but all are set to "latin_swedish_ci"

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated - thanx

Comment: Please give the `table structure`

Comment: `IMPLICIT` is about inSQL strings, not about some database fields. Using `utf8` everywhere should fix all this issues..

Comment: read [this](http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/) article also.

Answer (score 0):

`IMPLICIT` is about inSQL strings, not about some database fields.
Using `utf8` everywhere should fix all this issues..

Read [this](http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/) article about this issue.